# ExtJs6 grid column drag & drop

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to drag a column in a grid;
A grid has default drag events,as you know,just changing columns display place in order;
But my demand is when a column being dragged ,if dragged target-palce is not in
the grid header area ,the column will be removed, else if dragged target-place 
is in the grid header area,the column just change dispaly place to the target-place;
So how can I fix it ?